# IF X is Greater or Smaller than give an outcome

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need help with the following formula for Excel. 
It's not working, the only feedback I'm getting is `#VALUE!` outcome.
What I'm trying to do is simply:

- F5≥-8  = Big,
- -3≤F5≤-7.99999= Bigger,
- F5≥-2.9999999 = "Blank" <--- No outcome display required

```
=IF((F5)>=-8, "Big"),IF((F5)>=-3, "Bigger"), IF((F5)<=-1,",")
```

Comment: your application of IF function is incorrect. see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Comment: Thank @Rosetta for the answer and the article. Trying to understand.

Comment: @pnuts Nah, done with homework a long time ago. Using it for work to lessen the process of updating the file daily. Of course the feedback and value is not that in the file

Comment: `F5` cannot be ≥ -3 and ≤ -8 at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(F5>=-8, "Big",IF(F5>=-3, "Bigger", IF(F5<=-1,"Biggest","")))
```

---

I share the same thought with TotsieMae, you are absolutely right mate. The formula above is by syntax correct but logically not.

Anyway, if the formula involve too many IF functions, then it might be worth to consider an alternate form:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F5,{-8,"Big";-3,"Bigger";-1,"Biggest"},2,TRUE),"Big")
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't -3 and -1 larger than -8? Wouldn't this only return a value of **Big** so long as the number was -8 or higher (i.e. -7, -6, -5, etc.)? Maybe I'm overlooking something here? It seems `=IF(F5<=-8, "Big", IF(F5<=-3, "Bigger", IF(F5>-3,"","")))` would be more correct.

Comment: @TotsieMae Yup. You're right. I have yet to implement the formula

Comment: @Rosetta, I'm glad we got this one figured out as a team! :-)